# How to send pagination requests to firebase for endlessly scrollable recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, pagination

I'm trying to include pagination in my app what I want that for eg in my firebase I have 500 images that are to be shown in the recycler view what I want is first 10 or 15 images are loaded in the recycler view  at the beginning and when the user reaches to the end of the last item(image) it loads next 10 images (just like Instagram or facebook )

> Note:- if anyone wants more reference of my code please tell me I will
> update my question

**Here is my code**

**Home_Fragment.java**

```
private boolean loading = true;
    private int pastVisibleItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        MaterialToolbar materialToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        materialToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(toolbarItemClickListener);
        postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);
//        this is for one item per scroll
//        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
//        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(verticalRecyclerView);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
//        listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ListState");

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                staggeredGridLayoutManager
        );
        getData();


        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                visibleItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = staggeredGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
                firstVisibleItems = staggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
                if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
                    pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
                }

                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;
                        getData();
                        Log.d("tag", "LOAD NEXT ITEM");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
//        setupFirebaseAuth();
        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter_Home(getContext(), mUploads);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        postRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(Home_Fragment.saved_position);
        return view;
    }


    private void getData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        assert upload != null;
                        upload.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }
                postsAdapter.setUploads(mUploads);

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loading = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                loading = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**PostAdapter_Home.java** // Adapter Class

```
public class PostAdapter_Home extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter_Home.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    public Context mcontext;

    public PostAdapter_Home(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.ex_home, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Shimmer shimmer = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1)
                .setDropoff(50)
                .build();
        ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable();
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer);
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imageView);

//        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> changeScaleType(holder, position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public void setUploads(List<Upload> uploads){
        mUploads=uploads;
    }
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ShapeableImageView imageView;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePostHome);

        }


    }
}
```

**Update** // Added Upload.java file code as requested in the comment section

**Upload.java**

```
package com.example.myappnotfinal.AdaptersAndMore;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Upload {
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mKey;
    private String mUserName;
    private String mComment;

    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getmUserName() {
        return mUserName;
    }

    public void setmUserName(String mUserName) {
        this.mUserName = mUserName;
    }

    public String getmComment() {
        return mComment;
    }

    public void setmComment(String mComment) {
        this.mComment = mComment;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getmKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setmKey(String Key) {
        this.mKey = Key;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you could achieve that on the recycler view itself. I am a bit rusty on android, but try to load the items as you are scrolling. Meaning, you can load x amount of items (as many as it fits the screen) and as the user reaches the bottom of the screen you trigger an action to load the images.

 Now, in terms of speed and loading time, I advise you to look into the API call itself and to only trigger a new request on the event of the user reaching the bottom of the screen.

 Idk the terms of that, but lmk if you need some help in that, as far as I know that's a good logic to follow!

Comment: @TomasMota Thanks for the reply , ok I understand what you're trying to say but it will be very helpful if you explain it with some code though , Thanks once again

Comment: I'm HELLA rusty on Java for android dev. I'm gonna try and find you some articles explaining what you need to do. Please write a comment on what you are trying to achieve as briefly and concisely as you can and I'll make an answer to help anyone else with the same problem as you.

Comment: Btw, I do advise you to change to kotlin in the near future, since it is the firstly supported language by google.

Comment: What I want is for eg if there are lots of images in firebase let take 100 images that are been shown in a particular recycler view I want that at first 10 or 15 images should load in the adapter and when a user reaches the end next 5 images are loaded in the recycler view and the cycle repeats just how Instagram or Facebook do i want the same kind of functionality

Comment: yes I'm thinking to change to kotlin but worried about the community support on StackOverflow because I'm still new to android development  and the support is very good for java ut I don't know about kotlin

Comment: I advise you to try and find some tutorials on youtube, I unfortunately don't have enough knowledge to help you out on that :/

Comment: ok no problem thanks for the reply

Comment: In terms of changing to Kotlin, the community is well versed in Kotlin too and you can really get some amazing help. Also, I advise you to find some discord channels for Android development. There is a tone of them.

 Have a nice day my friend

Comment: show what is `Upload`?

Comment: Ok I have updated the question please check the Update section

Answer (score 1):

First you should separate fetching data logic from UI. Then your scroll controller (RecyclerView) should control which images should be called to download (so when it's loaded it should ask for first batch of images, when scroll happens - ask for another batch, etc.). And downloading and caching images is not a trivial task, that's why we have [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) in Android world.

As a side note please take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.

Please check what you're adding to the list of `mUploads` because every time you add items, you clear the list upfront `mUploads.clear();` which may be not what you wanted.

Some notes:

- dont make it static `public static List<Upload> mUploads;`
- don't need to store `mcontext`, Context is already there
- strip the problem out of unncessary stuff (e.g. drop shimmer, fix the problem, add shimmer when fixed)

Comment: can you please check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Here what you need to do is `setLimit` for pagination process.

Here is and **example:**

```
private void getUsers(String nodeId) {
Query query;

if (nodeId == null)
    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(Consts.FIREBASE_DATABASE_LOCATION_USERS)
            .orderByKey()
            .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);
else
    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(Consts.FIREBASE_DATABASE_LOCATION_USERS)
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt(nodeId)
            .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserModel user;
        List<UserModel> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            userModels.add(userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class));
        }

        mAdapter.addAll(userModels);
        mIsLoading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        mIsLoading = false;
    }
  });
}
```

So here you need to send last node id each time to get new list. After getting response just add your data to `ArrayList`  or what ever logic you are using. Then just update RecyclerView like this:

```
 blogRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                isScrolling = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
            totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
            scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems) && nextPage != null) {
                isScrolling = false;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 getUsers(mlastNodeId);//here your last id will be
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm understanding what you are trying to say but I have some doubts currently I don't have any user model of what should I do at UserModel, what should I do with that, please forgive me if I ask very dumb questions I'm new to android development

Comment: here you have to get your own model data or whatever data you need its just a sample im using in a project.

Comment: My pleasure hope you understand it clearly

Comment: can you tell me how can I create model data as you have shown or any resources on how can I create it, right now I have just stored all images in a simple container without any user, after some time I will add users too, but for right now I have only image URLs(Uri) for eg I have 500 images URL(Uri) nothing else

Comment: here is an ss of how I have  stored the data  on firebase https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iIAfPRofBVc1lei0AHyThcswqeu0p5j4/view?usp=sharing        I'm learning firebase so I have stored it in the simplest way so I can understand what's going on